# Get device date and time

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am able to get date picker from ionc2 [doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/datetime/DateTime/)

Could someone show me how to get device date and time in ionic2

Comment: `var now = new Date();`

Comment: could u give me a full example to make to this format m/d/y  h/m/s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [**momentjs**](https://momentjs.com/docs/) then you can easily handle date time use cases.

```
let currentDateTime = moment().format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss")
```

Install:

```
npm install moment --save
```

usage:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Moment with [**Typescript Doc**](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/)